# TV series intro flying through a cutting with obstacles

Tags: story-identification, tv

I recall a TV series having the intro (or possibly outro) from a plane/spaceship POV where it flew through a tunnel (or a cutting) with artificial walls looking like the [Death Star exterior](https://youtu.be/KuKqcfO31is?t=2), except the whole scene was much darker. In the tunnel/cutting there was a series of obstacles the ship cleared: alternatingly, the left and right parts of the tunnel were blocked by lit-up walls (so only half the space was available), then upper and lower parts. After going through a series of these obstacles, the ship encounters a lit-up wall (portal?) completely blocking the passage, possibly goes into it and the intro ends.

What is this series?

Meta:

- I recall seeing this in 1990s, broadcast on TV in Russia.
- I think this is a series because I recall seeing the intro not once but often (perhaps every week?)
- Unfortunately I don't remember any *actual* plot details.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're describing the end credits of *[Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)*:

We are flying along through a *Star Wars*-like trench, dodging shots of what looks like plasma from unseen guns, navigating between screens on the sides and the top and bottom. Several times, a space ship appears in front of us, which is shot with a blue beam. Finally, a sphere (or possibly a round screen) is encountered, which is shot and explodes ("hold on, I'm gonna blow this baby").

It's a late '80s series, so early '90s on Russian TV seems entirely possible.

Comment: This is it! Huh, those screens actually have different colors - I must have seen this in black & white...